# Changing primary monitor moves fullscreen window

Tags: winapi, user32

I'm trying to programmatically change the primary monitor on a Windows desktop PC.

When I change the primary display programmatically, a full-screen VMWare console window automatically moves to the new primary display.

I could also reproduce this using the NirSoft MultiMonitorTool https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html

```
.\MultiMonitorTool.exe /SetPrimary <monitor id>
```

The full screen VMWare console window does not move when performing the change from `Windows -> Settings -> Displays`

Note: Not reproducible for any full-screen windows. For example, a Chrome full-screen window stayed put.

Is there an alternative I haven't tried? Do I need to send extra messages to open windows? Can anyone figure out what Windows Settings is doing differently? I don't know my way around process explorer.

#### Initial config: Display 1 is primary / main

Display 2 {x= -3040, y = 0, extended} to the left of Display 1 {x=0, y=0, main}

On Display 1, I have a full-screen VMWarePlayer window.

#### Target config: Display 2 primary / main

Display 2 {x= 0, y = 0, main} to the left of Display 1 {x=3040, y=0, extended}

#### The issue

The VMWare window moves to Display 2. This does not happen when I do the change from `Windows -> Settings -> Displays`

I've had two approaches with the same result:

- `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` https://github.com/calin-darie/MouseBound/blob/master/MonitorChanger.cs Basiacally stolen from another Stack Overflow answer a while ago, same approach [indicated by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090604-00/?p=18023)
- `SetDisplayConfig`

```cs
GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS, out var pathCount, out var modeCount);

DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[] paths = new DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[pathCount];
DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[] modes = new DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[modeCount];

QueryDisplayConfig(QDC.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS, ref pathCount, paths, ref modeCount, modes);

var newPrimaryMode = modes[primaryMonitorIndex];
var oldPositionOfNewPrimary = newPrimaryMode.sourceMode.position;

for (var i = 0; i < modes.Length; i++)
{
    var mode = modes[i];
    modes[i].sourceMode.position = new Vanara.PInvoke.POINT(
        mode.sourceMode.position.X - oldPositionOfNewPrimary.X,
        mode.sourceMode.position.Y - oldPositionOfNewPrimary.Y);
}

SetDisplayConfig(pathCount, paths, modeCount, modes,
    SDC.SDC_APPLY | SDC.SDC_USE_SUPPLIED_DISPLAY_CONFIG | SDC.SDC_ALLOW_CHANGES);
```

Other, probably unimportant, details:

- Windows 10 version 22H2 at the time, but the issue can be reproduced in older versions as well, 2019 IIRC.
- VMWare Workstation Player 15.5.7 build-17171714